# Bit packing results in wrong value in Java

Tags: java, byte, bit

I have the following method in Java combine a set of four integer representation of bytes into a long.

```
public static long addBytesToInt(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4) {
    return ((x4 << 24) | (x3 << 16) | (x2 << 8) | (x1 & 0xFF));
}
```

But the problem is that if i would call this with for example the following values:

```
//1111 1111 0000 1111 0011 1100 0000 0011 = 4279188483    
addBytesToInt(3, 60, 15, 255);
```

It would return the wrong value. 
I had to change to the following code for it to work as intended and I cannot figure out why:

```
public static long addBytesToInt(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4) {
    long l = 0;

    l = (l << 8) + x4;
    l = (l << 8) + x3;
    l = (l << 8) + x2;
    l = (l << 8) + x1;

    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `((x4 << 24) | (x3 << 16) | (x2 << 8) | (x1 & 0xFF))` has to do with the types of the operands.  Since `x1` - `x4` all have type `int`, the result of each shift operation also has type `int`.  Therefore, the result of each arithmetic or operation has type `int`, too.  When `x4` has a value greater than 127, that final `int` result has its sign bit set, and therefore represents a negative number.  When that number is converted to `long` for return, the (negative) value is preserved.

Since the resulting `long` value has all its lower 32 bits set correctly, the easiest way to fix the problem is by masking off the 32 high-order bits.  I.e., apply an `& 0xffffffffL` operation to the current result.

The same does not apply to your working alternative.  Since variable `l` has type `long`, every operation produces a result of type `long`.  No overflow occurs, and the sign bit is never set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I have almost exactly the same function in C++ returning a long as well but it is working without me masking the bit before returning it, why is that? Would you recommend masking the returned value as well in my C++ function?

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer, in C++ you cannot rely on the `long` type to even be able to *represent* the value 4279188483.  C++ `long` can have as few as 31 value bits (plus one sign bit).  Moreover, in C++ it is not safe to perform a shift operation on an operand of signed type that produces an out-of-range result.  For portability, C++ code similar to your Java code should probably include `<cstdint>`, declare the return type to be `uint_least32_t`, and either declare the function arguments as `uint_least32_t` too, or else cast them to that type before shifting.

Comment: So basically you mean a function like: uint_least32_t addBytesToInt( uint_least32_t x1.. -  uint_least32_t x4) ? Also whats the difference with types like uint_least32_t and long int more than its unsigned? Do you oftean use theese kinds of types?

Comment: @BrokenProgrammer, yes, a function signature such as you present is consistent with my comments.  `uint_least32_t` is an alias for the narrowest unsigned integer type among those supported by your implementation that have at least 32 value bits.  You *need* 32 value bits, and if the type is unsigned then you don't need more.  You might also use `uint32_t`, but in principle, `uint_least32_t` is safer because there might not *be* a `uint32_t` on your implementation.  I do use those kinds of types regularly when the details of the numeric representation are important.